# Why do double quotes influence result in compareing datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

Why do these two results dont return the same results?

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE addtime > "2020-10-10" # returns several results

SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE addtime > 2020-10-10 # zero results
```

Can anyone explain why？

(`addtime` is datetime type.)

Comment: 2020-10-10 = 2000

Comment: `2020-10-10` is an arithmetic expression with the value of 2000. PS. In MySQL you must use single quotes `'`, not double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not do what you want:

```
where addtime > 2020-10-10
```

*Unquoted* `2020-10-10` is an arithmetic operation, which returns integer value `2000`. You are then asking MySQL to compare it with a date, so it tries to convert the integer to a date, which yields `null` - so the comparison is false for all rows.

On the other hand, in the other expression, the literal date is enclosed within double quotes, and MySQL recognizes it as such.

I would recommend single quotes for literal dates and strings; although MySQL allows double quotes for that purpose, this deviates from the SQL standard, where double quotes stand for identifiers (such as column names or table names), for no value added. So:

```
where addtime > '2020-10-10'
```

Comment: *so it tries to convert the integer to a date* This is ambiguous. User manual tells that an integer constant is converted to timestamp while compare with datetime column... but, from the other side, this is not a constant but (constant) expression...

Comment: @Akina: yes. I would suspect that an arithmetic expression of constants is still considered a constant though... But this indeed is not clearly written in the manual.